# read two excel headers using django pandas

Tags: django, pandas, excel, dataframe, django-views

From an excel table I need to read a budget using pandas.

**Input data**
In the first two lines are the columns with the header and content that will be used as objects to save in the *Sorder* class.
In the third line I have a new header for the product items.

[EXCEL Sorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgZgz.png)

```
client  payment_cond    interest_discount_table price_list  sorder_date requested_delivery_date
21101197111186  30/49   MT90    TEC9    01/11/2023  08/11/2023

product gross_price quantity            
LAAAAA1054  2   2           
LAAAAA0962  3   3
```

**Problem**
I can't get pandas to recognize this new header with the items.

```
if excel_file.name.endswith('.xls') or excel_file.name.endswith('.xlsx'):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        print("first two lines:")
        print(df.iloc[:1])
        print("third line onwards:")
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=2)
        base_row = df.iloc[2]
        print(df.iloc[2:])
        for index, row in df.iloc[2:].iterrows():
           product = row['product']
           gross_price = row['gross_price']
           qtd = row['qtd']
           product_base = base_row['product']
           gross_price_base = base_row['gross_price']
           qtd_base = base_row['qtd']
           print(f"product: {product}, gross_price: {gross_price}, qtd: {qtd}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're duplicating your self while using header and also using iloc method. It will remove rows from your dataframe.

```
if excel_file.endswith('.xls') or excel_file.endswith('.xlsx'): 
    try: 
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    except:
        return 

    print("first two lines:")
    print(df.iloc[:1])

    print("third line onwards:")

    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=2)

    base_row = df.iloc[1]

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        product = row['product']
        gross_price = row['gross_price']
        qtd = row['quantity']
            
        product_base = base_row['product']
        gross_price_base = base_row['gross_price']
        qtd_base = base_row['quantity']

        print(
            f"product: {product}, gross_price: {gross_price}, qtd: {qtd}")
```

Comment: Hi. Were you able to validate your result with provided input data?